# Android - how to install apk from SD card

Tags: sd-card, installation, apk

Is it possible to install an app to an Android phone from an SD card?  To install it without a data connection, the marketplace, or using ADB?

I've tried searching for this but no luck so far.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a file browser app installed, such as ASTRO, you can browse to the apk file on your SD card, click the apk, and it should pop up the apk installer.

Comment: You also have to enable unknown sources.

Comment: Another way is to copy it to the download folder of the browser (which can vary, so find it first) and than go over the browser to the downloaded files and start it from there.

Answer (score 4):

Simply call the following URL in your browser:

file:///sdcard/yourApp.apk

It works!