# Installing .apk to Android 5 Device (Zebra TC70) from web browser (2024)

Tags: sd-card

If possible, I would like to avoid using the Android Playstore and point the we browser to the External SD card for installation.

I tried call the following URL in the Chrome browser:

```
file:///sdcard/
```

Source: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/8386/203524

The browser returns the internal sd-memory and not the SD card.  The target .apk file is in the root of the SD card.

I've also tried:

```
file:///external_sd/yourApp.apk

file:///sdcard/external_sd/yourApp.apk
```

source: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/8356/203524

Is it possible to a install the .apk from the SD card through the web browser?

Update:

I uploaded the .apk to Google Drive, downloaded, but when I click the file, "Can't open file is returned".

Comment: This will vary **widely** depending on the make, model, perhaps even between builds.  However, in my experience, aside from allowing `install from unknown sources` permission to the OEM browser, you may also need to enable "debug mode" to allow local read/write access from the browser (I've seen some browsers that take this in the form of a line of .js directly inputted through the omnibox).  It might make better sense to use a file manager (such as, e.g., [X-plore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lonelycatgames.Xplore))

Comment: That `file:///sdcard/` points to the internal storage is a historic relic. In Android 2.x `/sd-card` was referring to the sd-card, but the smartphone bot plenty of flash storage and a physical sd-card wasn't necessary anymore. Note that both linked questions are pretty old. At the time of writing Android 4 ICS was brand new. A lot has changed since that time.

Comment: Looks like there are 2 subtle different questions: the title (install APK from a web browser) and the question (install APK *on the external SD card* from a web browser). If it's the former, have you tried putting the APK on the internal storage and opening it from the browser? If it's the latter, then maybe try the locations from [the answers on this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/137031/44325)?

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks for the helpful link.  I would prefer to learn how to directly install from the SD card.  I uploaded the .apk to Google Drive, downloaded, but when I click the file, "Can't open file is returned".